# Bootstrap New Window Popup Layout Missing Scrollbars

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC Layout page that my new windows use that does not have the code for the nav bar, since it just shouldn't.

Here is the relevant code for /Views/Shared/_Popup.chstml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")@Styles.Render("~/Content/DataTables-1.11.2")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">@RenderBody()</div>
</body>
```

The pages that are not new windows use the default /Views/Shared/_Layout.chstml and have scrollbars appearing as expected.  How can I get scrollbars on my new windows once they get big enough?

Comment: not able to understand question .. plz give some more explanation what you want actually..

Comment: When I open new page the scroll bar is missing ...

Comment: its may be due to page height or width is smaller than that of window???

Comment: Nop,already check it...

Comment: Whats wrong with body{overflow-y: scroll;} in your markup? You would also make sure your page is not popping left and right when the content length exceeds window height.